# Find intervals between times in a column

Tags: r, date

I feel like there must be a cleaner way to do this. This is a silly example but say I have data.frame like this (omitting the obvious nonsense that is has a constant interval):

```
df = data.frame(date_time = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-05-29 08:15:00 UTC"), 
                                as.POSIXct("2017-05-30 08:15:00 UTC"), by = "5 min"),
                group = "temp")
```

So say that I didn't actually know what the interval was or that it wasn't constant. My question is what is the best way to find the interval between dates in a column. I have come up with something using a loop but I am wondering if there are better solutions out there:

```
int_time = c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  tmp = as.numeric(df$date_time[i+1] - df$date_time[i] )
  int_time = c(tmp, int_time)
}
```

Comment: Maybe `diff(df$date_time)`?

Comment: Yikes did I over complicate that. Want to put it as an answer? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` accepts a number of data types and has a method specifically for vectors of the POSIXt class. In this instance

```
head(diff(df$date_time))
```

returns

```
Time differences in mins
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Because you are taking pairwise differences, you will lose an observation. To put this back into your dataset, you have two choices.

For d_i = x_i - x_{i-1}, use

```
df$int_time <- c(NA, diff(df$date_time))
```

For d_i = x_{i + 1} - x_i, use

```
df$int_time <- c(diff(df$date_time), NA)
```

Comment: Can you recommend the best approach to add this back into the data.frame? `> df$int_time <- diff(df$date_time)`. Then this error `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, int_time, value = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  : replacement has 288 rows, data has 289`